# How to pass the return value of a command as a parameter to another command in bash?

Tags: android, bash, parameter-passing

I'm writing a shell script in Android.
I need to determine the name of the owner of an app's data directory, assign it to a variable and change the owner of another directory (which happens to be a sub-directory of the first directory) to the owner of the first directory using a variable.

```
#assign the owner of the com.netflix.mediaclient to $user variable
user=`su -c "ls -l /data/data | grep com.netflix.mediaclient | cut -f2 -d' '"`
#change the owner of the shared_prefs directory to the value in $user variable
su -c 'busybox chown -R '$user:$user' /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient/shared_prefs'
```

This and many other variations of the syntax of the second line does not work.

```
#using double quotes
su -c 'busybox chown -R "$user:$user" /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient/shared_prefs'
#using no quotes
su -c 'busybox chown -R $user:$user /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient/shared_prefs'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat` to find the owner and put `$user:$user` inside double quotes

```
user="$( busybox  stat -c '%U' /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient )"
busybox chown -R "$user:$user" /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient/shared_prefs
```

---

Why `'$user:$user'` will not work?

Anything put inside the singles quotes are taken literally by bash and variable expansion will not occur.

Comment: The stat command in android shell does not seem to have a -c switch. Not even in the busybox binary

Comment: @Prashan : It is understandable that  ` -c switch` might be missing but what do you mean by `Not even in the busybox binary `?

Comment: I meant the busybox version of stat command doesn't have the -c switch either. (i.e. busybox  stat -c '%U' /data/data/com.netflix.mediaclient does not work). But the problem is with the syntax of the second command isn't it? Fixing the first command should not affect it right?

Comment: @Prashan : Please update the error you've got with the second command, if there is no error but the command doesn't do what it is supposed to do, post that too.